What is FN vs FUNCTION difference?
is there a difference between the following codes? I've converted from old PHP and trying to make it 8.1 compatible, and ChatGTP 3.5 and 4.0 gave different answers
ORG
add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("td_block_widget");'));

GPT 3.5
add_action('widgets_init', fn() => register_widget("td_block_widget"));

GPT 4.0
add_action('widgets_init', function() {
    return register_widget("td_block_widget");
});


For this example there is no difference. The middle example is called an arrow function or short closure. Docs here and summary here giving details about the difference with regular functions.

They are all the same here, but I really don't like the 1st one

create_function() is not equivalent to the other two. As the manual says: "This function internally performs an eval() and as such has the same security issues as eval(). It also has bad performance and memory usage characteristics, because the created functions are global and can not be freed.". That sounds very different. Don't use it. The difference between the other two is quite obvious. An arrow function has a nice short syntax but cannot be expanded like a normal closure.
